# Extjs : How can I use seperate .js files?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

My project is going to be so large. I decided to keep my Extjs codes in seperate files. How xan I do it please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare some Extjs components into another .js file But you have to import both files in html document.